# Why are there relatively many Eastern European (specifically Hungarian) graph theorists?

Tags: mathematicians, mathematics-social-history, combinatorics, graph-theory

I noticed that a large number of theories within graph theory are from Eastern European graph theorists, specifically Hungarian graph theorists. What is the relation between Eastern Europe (specifically Hungary) and the emergence of these theories within graph theory? Is there anything written about the history of this? I cannot find anything about this topic while I find it interesting to think about the history of some political/academic/societal state and the emergence of theories within a particular field.

Comment: Perhaps it is: one professor and his students and their students...  This interpretation could be investigated at https://www.mathgenealogy.org

Comment: Tibor's [The Social Construction of Hungarian Genius](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/242572746_The_Social_Construction_of_Hungarian_Genius) provides some interesting historical background.

Comment: Three reasons come to mind, [Dénes Kőnig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9nes_K%C5%91nig), [KöMaL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A1szl%C3%B3_R%C3%A1tz#K%C3%B6z%C3%A9piskolai_Matematikai_%C3%A9s_Fizikai_Lapok,_K%C3%B6MaL) and [Paul Erdős](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Erd%C5%91s).